# como generar CHANEL ID ANDROID 8

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de colocar un servicio en primer plano en android 8, para ello se debe crear una notificación permanente, pero me pide adicionalmente un CHANEL_ID, pero no se como generarlo o buscarlo para incluir el parámetro.

un ejemplo que encontre, bàsico pone algo como:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setContentText(mensaje)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Pero aùn no se como generar el `ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID`

Me podrían ayudar por favor.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear la notificación de la siguiente manera:

```
public class NotificationUtils extends ContextWrapper {

private NotificationManager mManager;
public static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "com.chikeandroid.tutsplustalerts.ANDROID";
public static final String IOS_CHANNEL_ID = "com.chikeandroid.tutsplustalerts.IOS";
public static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME = "ANDROID CHANNEL";
public static final String IOS_CHANNEL_NAME = "IOS CHANNEL";

public NotificationUtils(Context base) {
    super(base);
    createChannels();
}

public void createChannels() {

    // create android channel
    NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
            ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
    androidChannel.enableLights(true);
    // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
    androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
    // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
    androidChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
    androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);

    // create ios channel
    NotificationChannel iosChannel = new NotificationChannel(IOS_CHANNEL_ID,
            IOS_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    iosChannel.enableLights(true);
    iosChannel.enableVibration(true);
    iosChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
    iosChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(iosChannel);
}

private NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (mManager == null) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mManager;
}
}
```

En el ejemplo se crean dos instancias de NotificationChannel, pasando un id (que debe ser único dentro de tu paquete), un nombre de cana, y también un nivel de importancia en su constructor.

La lista completa de opciones de importancia disponibles son:

- IMPORTANCE_MAX: si nusar
- IMPORTANCE_HIGH: se muestra en todos lados, hace ruido y se asoma
- IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT: se muestra en todos lados, hace ruido, pero no estorba visualmente
- IMPORTANCE_LOW: se muestra en todos lados, pero no es intrusiva
- IMPORTANCE_MIN: se muestra solo en la sombra, debajo del doblez
- IMPORTANCE_NONE: una notificación sin importancia; no se muestra en la sombra

Comment: Gracias, lo resolvi con el siguiente codigo:

Answer (score 0):

lo resolvi creando el siguiente codigo:

```
public class NotificationUtils extends ContextWrapper{
private NotificationManager mManager;
private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "www.linkedin.com.in.wisrovi.rodriguez";
private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME = "ANDROID CHANNEL";

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public NotificationUtils(Context base) {
    super(base);
    createChannels();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void createChannels() {
    NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
            ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    androidChannel.enableLights(true);
    androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
    androidChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
    androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
}

private NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (mManager == null) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mManager;
}

public String getAndroidChannelId(){
    return ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public NotificationCompat.Builder BuilderAndroid8(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID);
    return builder;
}
```

}

y luego:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationUtils(context).BuilderAndroid8();
```

coloco los parametros que builder que deseo configurar y lanzo la notificacion seguida de `startForeground(1,notificacion)`

Answer (score 0):

A partir de [Android 8.0 tienes que configurar un canal](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) para que las Push Notifications puedan ser recibidas.

`Notification.Builder` ahora requiere un identificador del canal:

**[Notification.Builder (Context context, 
                String channelId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#Notification.Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))**

Lo único que tienes que hacer es definir un

```
private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "Noticias";

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(mensaje)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Recuerda crear también un [**NotficationChannel**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    NotificationChannel channelBN = new NotificationChannel("noticias", "Noticias", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channelBN.setDescription("La información más relevante del día.");
    channelBN.setVibrationPattern(new long[] { 500, 1000 });
    NotificationChannel channelCN = new NotificationChannel("custom_notifications", "Personalizadas", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channelCN.setDescription("Recibe las información más relevante.");
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(nm != null){
        nm.createNotificationChannel(channelBN);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(channelCN);
    }

}
```